# Redirect URL in IIS to different domain and remove portions of the URL

Tags: iis, redirect, rewrite, url

We currently have URLs like:

```
https://tfs.mydomain.com/tfs/MyProjectCollection/Project/_workitems
```

that I need redirected to:

```
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/Project/_workitems
```

Using the HTTP Redirect module in IIS I've been able to forward requests from `https://tfs.mydomain.com` to `https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg` without any issue.

The problem is that when it's a deep link, I need to remove the `/tfs/MyProjectCollection` portion of the link when redirecting it. With my current setup of just redirecting the root domain, a request to:

```
https://tfs.mydomain.com/tfs/MyProjectCollection/Project/_workitems
```

ends up getting redirected to:

```
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/tfs/MyProjectCollection/Project/_workitems
```

instead of the desired:

```
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/Project/_workitems
```

This is what my web.config currently looks like:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can I strip out the `/tfs/MyProjectCollection` portion of the URL when redirecting it?

---

Update: I have also tried installing the URL Rewrite module and setting up my web.config like this, but still have the same results.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="IQProjectCollection" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^tfs/IQProjectCollection$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.azure.com/iqmetrix" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="tfs" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^tfs$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.azure.com/iqmetrix" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="home" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.azure.com/iqmetrix" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer by stumbling across [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18625273/602585). Using the IIS URL Rewrite module, this is what my web.config now looks like to do what I want. Note that the order of the rules does matter (most specific to least specific):

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="IQProjectCollection" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^tfs/MyProjectCollection/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="tfs" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^tfs/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="home" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```